# Change permalink for default archive - yearly

Tags: url-rewriting, archives

I want to change the structure of yearly archive URL of default post type `post`.

As we know that default URL structure is like:

Default: `http://wwww.domain.com/2005`

but want them rewritten, so end up like this:

New: `http://wwww.domain.com/archive/2005`

I tried following but do seem to work:

```
function wpa116030_init(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->date_structure = 'archive/%year%/';
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa116030_init' );
```

But it does not work.

I'd like someone to point to the right direction, need more info do leave a comment.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work but note that the date structure contains the structure for year, month and day archives as well, so you'll need something like:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->date_structure = 'archives/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%';
});
```

Don't forget to visit your permalinks settings page in wp-admin so that rewrite rules are flushed.

Comment: This didn't work for me in June 2021